# sysfs_store gets called multiple times after error is returned

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, sysfs

I created a kernel module with the following function for test purposes:

```
ssize_t sysfs_store(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
     const char *buffer, size_t count)
{

    printk(KERN_ERR "test" );
    return -EINVAL;
}
```

However, "test" is printed 3 times.

From the kernel documentation:

> - show() or store() can always return errors. If a bad value comes
>     through, be sure to return an error.

How do I make sure the function is not called anymore when an error is returned?

Comment: If you put `pr_err("test\n");` instead, would it work as expected?

Comment: Number of function's calls depends on number of writing into corresponding sysfs file. If a user tries to write the file 3 times, the functions will be called 3 times too. However, it has a little sense to limit function calls. What is important, is what function will actually do during these calls. E.g. you may create a flag variable which is checked at the beginning of the function and is reset when the function returns an error.

Comment: What is send by the user is for example: echo "w 1 51 1" > /sys/kernel/es/data

Comment: Invocation of `echo` should generate single call to `.store()` function.

Comment: @Mathijs, had you tried what I suggested?